# Save List to file on disk

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I build WPF program , And i use this code to save a `List` of objects to a File:

```
    var list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add("item1");
    list.Add("item2");

    // Serialize the list to a file
    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("test.dat"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
    }
```

And my problem is where to save this file on the disk. i read that i can't use the `ProgramFiles` Folder because sometimes only the admin user can save to this folder files.

There is any universal folder that i can use to save files?

Comment: Common location is the same place as the application itself. You can add sub folder "data" to prevent the end user from getting confused or delete your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd save it to Application Data. You can get it's path using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Comment: I see that this method return `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming` . And if i want that this data will be visible to every user on the computer?

Comment: here is the complete list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Comment: @MTA if you want it for all users use CommonApplicationData see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx . It's typical to create a folder for your application/company under there.

Answer (score 2):

Is this data internal to your program, or user generated? If the data is internal, you probably want to use the Application Data folder. If it's user generated, you should probably default to My Documents, but let the user to decide where to save it.

You can call [Environment.GetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to get the location of these special folders.

Comment: Thank!! what is the different between Application Data folder and Documents??

Comment: Application Data (something like `C:\Users\username\AppData` is where programs can store data they need to operate, and is equivalent to storing something in Program Files in the old days. Documents is the user's My Documents folder, where they save their files.